# How to hide a parent component when switching to a child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

When I start the application, I have the "AppComponent" component displayed. Through it, using `AuthGuard` I turn or do not go to the module routes: `GalleryModule`. My problem is that when I go over the child routes `GalleryAddComponent` or `GalleryItemComponent` to `GalleryComponent`, my father `GalleryComponent` does not hide, and the child component is displayed below. and I need that during the transition on the child `GalleryAddComponent` and `GalleryItemComponent` my father would hide `GalleryComponent`. How to implement it?

**Structure of my project:**

[image]

**AppRoutingModule:**

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'app-root'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

**GalleryRoutingModule:**

```js
const galleryRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'gallery',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: GalleryComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'gallery-add', component: GalleryAddComponent},
            {path: 'galleryItem/:id', component: GalleryItemComponent},
        ]
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(galleryRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: []
})
```

**template of GalleryComponent:**

```html
 <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12">
                <h1>{{gallery}}</h1>
                <div class="create-post">
                    <a routerLink="gallery-add" class="btn btn-outline-success tog" >
                        Add New Post
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6" *ngFor="let pic of collection">
            <a [routerLink]="['galleryItem', pic.id]">
                <img [src]="pic.url" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
                <p class="lead"><span>{{pic.id}}:</span>{{pic.title}}</p>
            </a>
            <div class="card buttons">
                <a class="btn btn-danger del" (click)="removePost(pic.id)">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Seems you need `router-outlet`. Pls add `app.component.html` in to your question.

Comment: @ User3250 i have router-outlet in app.component
i need hide GalleryComponent when  i go to GalleryAddComponent or GalleryItemComponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the placement of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. It should not be in `gallery.component.html`. If you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app.component.html then it will handle the routing.

In short just remove `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

### Alternative

If you are facing the issue related AuthGuard. Create new Component which handles the routing for the Gallery.

## Follow these steps

> 1. Create Main Component for Gallary

### gallery-main.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### gallery-main.component.ts

```
@Component
Class GalleryMainComponent{

}
```

> 2. Change in the routing-

```
const galleryRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: GalleryMainComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent},
            {path: 'gallery-add', component: GalleryAddComponent},
            {path: 'galleryItem/:id', component: GalleryItemComponent},
        ]
    },
];
```

Note : Do not forget to remove the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from `gallery.component.html`

Comment: yes i have <router-outlet></router-outlet> in  app.component.html  but if i remove <router-outlet></router-outlet> from  gallery.component.html  then I don't see my child components when navigating through them of  GalleryComponent

Comment: Updated the answer. It will be better if you can share your `app.component.html`.

Answer (score 1):

SO you have to remove the child routes from **GalleryRoutingModule**.  And **router-outlet** from the Gallerycomponent. And need to make the routes normal way (no nested/ child routes ) in the **GalleryRoutingModule**

Comment: I did it before, then I need to write "canActivate: [AuthGuard]" for each component this is a dubbing

Comment: you can do one more thing create a default route in child routes that pointing to the Gallerycomponent html

Answer (score 1):

**Service:**

```
public navigation = new Subject<any>();
public navigation$ = this.navigation.asObservable();
```

In GalleryAddComponent & GalleryItemComponent, You can create emit an observable using service.

```
this.service.navigation.next(true);
```

In Gallery Component, you can subscribe to listen for the changes.

```
public displayGalleryContent = true;
this.service.navigation$.subscribe((isreached)=>{
  if(isreached){
     this.displayGalleryContent = true;
  }
});
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngIf="displayGalleryContent"></div>
```